# How to add an oversized button in the middle of a toolbar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am writing a camera app and I need to create a toolbar (at the bottom of the screen of course) with 3 buttons, the middle button needs to be oversized exceeding the height of the navigation bar showing the image of a camera.

It is unclear to me how to add a button to the toolbar that is about 20% higher than the toolbar itself.

I have seen some designs out there and it looks really slick, but how do I configure such button programatically?

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could start by creating your own UIView which will contain all the buttons.

Add each button in and position it, including the oversized middle button - position it at a -y coordinate (e.g. -10).

Then set the container UIView Clips Subviews to NO - this can be done in IB or programatically - `self.view.clipsToBounds = NO`

This will allow the middle button to flow outside of its parent container.

Answer (score 0):

You could just make a button and put it over the top of the tab bar. Or make your own tab bar in photoshop or something.

Answer (score 0):

I havent used this myself, but I think it describes what you're after.

https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

If you're looking to modify the UI of the camera controls themselves, then that is probably more difficult to achieve.